# Transformation of coordinates, Concept

Tags: matlab

i want to convert x,y,z coordinates to polar coordinates. I am getting (-) in y coordiantes. Can someone explain me why I am getting it. It would be great help.

I am reading these values (xyz ,  az_elev_r) from a software and can't be changed.I am just not sure of the order of angles( az & elev). Using my code I get -y instead of y. It means there is 180 rotation.My code is:

```
xyz=[-0.564 3.689 -0.735;
      2.011 5.067 -1.031;
     -1.181 3.943 -1.825; % Reference values
    ];
```

%% az_elev_r-->xyz

```
 az_elev_r=[ 261.30 -11.24 3.80;
               291.65 -10.692 5.548;
               253.34 -23.897 4.50]; % Also Reference (degree)



az_elev_r(:,1:2)=deg2rad(az_elev_r(:,1:2));

r=az_elev_r(:,3);
az=az_elev_r(:,1);
elev=az_elev_r(:,2);


x=r.*cos(az).*cos(elev)
y=r.*sin(az).*cos(elev)
z=r.*sin(elev)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `az_elev_r` matrix is not consistent with your `xyz` reference.

```
>> [az, el, r] = cart2sph(xyz(:,1), xyz(:,2), xyz(:,3));
>> rad2deg(az)
ans =
          98.6924675475501
          68.3527736950233
          106.673911589314
```

Your answers are consistent with the values returned by the `sph2cart` function.  (Example starts with your original input, before the `dec2rad` replacement.

```
>> [x, y, z] = sph2cart(deg2rad(az_elev_r(:,1)), deg2rad(az_elev_r(:,2)), az_elev_r(:,3))
x =
         -0.563766229670505
          2.01131973806906
         -1.17951822049783
y =
         -3.68422880893852
         -5.06709019311118
         -3.94153436658676
z =
         -0.740692730942158
         -1.02931719412937
         -1.82292172199717
```

Incidentally, you're code will be more readable if you just use the `sph2cart` function, and work in radians, unless you are trying to understand the conversions for their own sake.

Comment: I am reading these values (xyz ,  az_elev_r) from a software and can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has the code for conversion to polar coordinates and back. This conversion is useful for finding object rotation through correlation or otherwise creating object-centred 'rotation-independent' representation of objects. It is useful to visualize each of the polar coordinates as well as their joint image. The images below should be self_explanatory. The polar plot has angle as a horizontal axis and Radius as a vertical axis, so that 4 peaks correspond to the 4 corners of the input image. The code (C++ with OpenCV) is attached. 
[image: Polar coordinate visualization]

```
//================================
// Name        : PolarCoord.cpp
// Author      : V.Ivanchenko cudassimo@gmail.com
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//======================================

#include <iostream>
#include "opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define VALID(x, y, w, h) ((x)>=0 && (y)>=0 && (x)<(w) && (y)<(h)) // validates index

/*
 *   1. Original binary image HxW CV_8U
 *              |
 *              |
 *              V
 *   2. Two coordinate Mats HxW CV_32F
 *              |
 *              |
 *              V
 *   3. Visualization CV_8U
 *      a. gray HxW for a single coordinate image
 *      b. binary Rx360 for two coordinate images
 */

// convert a binary 2D image into two Mats with float coordiantes
void imageToCoord(const Mat& img, Mat& X, Mat& Y, bool centered = true) {
    if (img.empty())
        return;

    int h = img.rows;
    int w = img.cols;
    X.create(h, w, CV_32F);
    Y.create(h, w, CV_32F);
    float Cx = w/2.0f;
    float Cy = h/2.0f;

    for (int i=0; i<h; ++i){
        const uchar* img_row = img.ptr<uchar>(i);
        float* x_row = X.ptr<float>(i);
        float* y_row = Y.ptr<float>(i);

        for (int j=0; j<w; ++j) {
            if (img_row[j]>0) {
                float x = j;
                float y = i;
                if (centered) {
                    x-=Cx;
                    y-=Cy;
                }
                x_row[j] = x;
                y_row[j] = y;
            }
        } // j
    } // i
} //imageToCoord()

// convert a single float ploar coord Mat to a gray image
void polarToImg(const Mat& PolarCoord, Mat& img) {
    if (PolarCoord.empty())
        return;

    int h = PolarCoord.rows;
    int w = PolarCoord.cols;
    img.create(h, w, CV_8U);
    float maxVal = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();

    // find maxVal
    for (int i=0; i<h; ++i){
        const float* x_row = PolarCoord.ptr<float>(i);
        for (int j=0; j<w; ++j) {
            if (maxVal < x_row[j])
                maxVal = x_row[j];
        } // j
    } // i

    // create an image
    if (maxVal>0) {
        float k = 255.0/maxVal;
        for (int i=0; i<h; ++i){
            uchar* img_row = img.ptr<uchar>(i);
            const float* x_row = PolarCoord.ptr<float>(i);
            for (int j=0; j<w; ++j) {
                img_row[j] = saturate_cast<uchar>(k*x_row[j]);
            }// j
        } // i
    } // if
} // plarToImg()

// convert two polar coord Mats to a binary image
void polarToImg(const Mat& radius, const Mat& angle, Mat& img) {
    if (angle.empty() || radius.empty())
        return;

    int h = angle.rows;
    int w = angle.cols;
    assert(radius.cols==w && radius.rows==h);
    const int imgH = sqrt(h*h+w*w)+0.5f; // radius
    const int imgW = 360;                 // angle, deg
    img.create(imgH, imgW, CV_8U);

    // create an image
    for (int i=0; i<h; ++i){
        const float* ang_row = angle.ptr<float>(i);
        const float* r_row = radius.ptr<float>(i);

        for (int j=0; j<w; ++j) {
            int x = ang_row[j] + 0.5f;
            int y = r_row[j] + 0.5f;

            if (x>0) {
                cout<<x<<endl;
            }
            if (VALID(x, y, imgW, imgH))
                img.at<uchar>(y, x) = 255;
            else {
                cout<<"Invalid x, y: "<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
            }
        }// j
    } // i
} // plarToImg()

int main() {
    cout << "Cartesian to polar" << endl; // prints "Syntax training in openCV"
    const int W=400, H=400;
    Mat Minput(H, W, CV_8U);
    Minput(Rect(W/4, H/4, W/2, H/2)) = 255;
    Mat X, Y, Angle, Radius, Mr, Mang, Mpolar;

    // processing
    imageToCoord(Minput, X, Y);             // extract coordinates
    cartToPolar(X, Y, Radius, Angle, true);// convert coordiantes

    // visualize
    polarToImg(Radius, Mr);
    polarToImg(Angle, Mang);
    polarToImg(Radius, Angle, Mpolar);

    // debug
    //cout<<Mpolar<<endl;

    namedWindow("input", 0);
    namedWindow("angle", 0);
    namedWindow("radius", 0);
    namedWindow("Polar", 0);

    const int winw=200, winh=200;
    resizeWindow("input", winw, winh);
    resizeWindow("angle", winw, winh);
    resizeWindow("radius", winw, winh);
    resizeWindow("Polar", 360, (int)sqrt(H*H + W*W));

    moveWindow("input", 0, 0);
    moveWindow("angle", winw, 0);
    moveWindow("radius", 2*winw, 0);
    moveWindow("Polar", 3*winw, 0);

    imshow("input", Minput);
    imshow("angle", Mang);
    imshow("radius", Mr);
    imshow("Polar", Mpolar);
    waitKey(-1);

    return 0;
}
```